# E-mail app/filter that copies E-mail from the body of the letter and auto replies to that e-mail

Tags: email, gmail

i need to set up my e-mail to autoreply to a certain adress that is usually on  the body of the sentence.

For example, Letter 1:

```
from: sender@mail.com
to: me@gmail.com
body: Hello. New customer's details. 
Email: |newmail1@mail.com|
```

Letter 2:

```
from: sender@mail.com
to: me@gmail.com
body: Hello. New customer's details. 
Email: |newmail1@mail.com|
```

I have to be able to extract that data and reply to it (newmail1@mail.com | newmail2@gmail.com). I already tried Gmail, but it doesnt have such advanced filter. Does anybody know apps or email services that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking out Google Apps Script. You can create a script just like you would create any other Google Document in Drive by adding the Scripts module from the app store (Scripts is free and created by google). You can also use the gmail API to do the same thing.

Both are very well documented and provide a surprisingly high level of access to your emails and their content.